# Give context-free grammars that generate the following language

Tags: finite-automata, automata, state-machine, automata-theory

Give context-free grammars that generate the following language.
In all parts the alphabet ∑ is {x,s}.
{w| w starts and ends with the different symbols}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
S -> xAs | sAx
A -> xA | sA | xAs | sAx | e
```

`e` = epsilon

Comment: one of my colleague reject it and suggest me given below:
S -> xAs | sAx
A -> xA | sA | e